# Accuracy with TPU seems to be less than with GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, tpu

I am trying to train a simple CNN in colab with TPU. However it appears it is not reaching the same level of accuracy as that of using a GPU. I would like to know if I am missing something. Please advise.

Data set is MNIST
Framework: tf.keras (Tensorflow 2.0)
Below are the details :

Neural Network :

```
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28,28,1), use_bias = False))
  model.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation = 'relu', use_bias = False))
  model.add(Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size=(3,3), activation = 'relu', use_bias = False))
  model.add(MaxPool2D())
  model.add(Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size=(1,1), activation = 'relu', use_bias = False))
  model.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation = 'relu', use_bias = False))
  model.add(Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size=(3,3), activation = 'relu', use_bias = False))
  model.add(Conv2D(filters = 10, kernel_size = (1, 1) , activation='relu', use_bias = False))
  model.add(Conv2D(filters = 10, kernel_size = (7, 7), use_bias = False))
  model.add(Flatten())
  model.add(Activation('softmax'))
  model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
             optimizer='adam',
             metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Training log with GPU(In Colab) :

```
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=10, validation_data = (X_test, Y_test), verbose=1)
```

```
Train on 60000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
Epoch 1/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 19s 316us/sample - loss: 0.2102 - accuracy: 0.9328 - val_loss: 0.0627 - val_accuracy: 0.9780
Epoch 2/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 16s 259us/sample - loss: 0.0550 - accuracy: 0.9838 - val_loss: 0.0374 - val_accuracy: 0.9879
Epoch 3/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 16s 259us/sample - loss: 0.0390 - accuracy: 0.9878 - val_loss: 0.0339 - val_accuracy: 0.9904
Epoch 4/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 15s 258us/sample - loss: 0.0309 - accuracy: 0.9905 - val_loss: 0.0324 - val_accuracy: 0.9899
Epoch 5/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 15s 257us/sample - loss: 0.0261 - accuracy: 0.9916 - val_loss: 0.0314 - val_accuracy: 0.9912
Epoch 6/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 15s 257us/sample - loss: 0.0218 - accuracy: 0.9931 - val_loss: 0.0322 - val_accuracy: 0.9908
Epoch 7/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 15s 258us/sample - loss: 0.0183 - accuracy: 0.9942 - val_loss: 0.0325 - val_accuracy: 0.9911
Epoch 8/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 15s 257us/sample - loss: 0.0159 - accuracy: 0.9945 - val_loss: 0.0384 - val_accuracy: 0.9884
Epoch 9/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 15s 256us/sample - loss: 0.0149 - accuracy: 0.9953 - val_loss: 0.0509 - val_accuracy: 0.9869
Epoch 10/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 15s 256us/sample - loss: 0.0126 - accuracy: 0.9961 - val_loss: 0.0295 - val_accuracy: 0.9923
```

Training log with TPU(In Colab) :

```
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=128, steps_per_epoch=468, epochs=15, validation_data = (X_test, Y_test), verbose=1)
```

```
Epoch 1/15
461/468 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2352 - accuracy: 0.9256INFO:tensorflow:Running validation at fit epoch: 0
79/79 [==============================] - 59s 752ms/step
79/79 [==============================] - 59s 752ms/step
468/468 [==============================] - 101s 215ms/step - loss: 0.2328 - accuracy: 0.9264 - val_loss: 0.0670 - val_accuracy: 0.9786
Epoch 2/15
466/468 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0573 - accuracy: 0.9827INFO:tensorflow:Running validation at fit epoch: 1
79/79 [==============================] - 62s 790ms/step
79/79 [==============================] - 62s 790ms/step
468/468 [==============================] - 103s 221ms/step - loss: 0.0572 - accuracy: 0.9827 - val_loss: 0.0462 - val_accuracy: 0.9850
Epoch 3/15
460/468 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0407 - accuracy: 0.9878INFO:tensorflow:Running validation at fit epoch: 2
79/79 [==============================] - 67s 844ms/step
79/79 [==============================] - 67s 844ms/step
468/468 [==============================] - 111s 237ms/step - loss: 0.0402 - accuracy: 0.9880 - val_loss: 0.0477 - val_accuracy: 0.9836
Epoch 4/15
466/468 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0342 - accuracy: 0.9898INFO:tensorflow:Running validation at fit epoch: 3
79/79 [==============================] - 67s 848ms/step
79/79 [==============================] - 67s 848ms/step
468/468 [==============================] - 110s 234ms/step - loss: 0.0341 - accuracy: 0.9898 - val_loss: 0.0453 - val_accuracy: 0.9860
Epoch 5/15
461/468 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0279 - accuracy: 0.9916INFO:tensorflow:Running validation at fit epoch: 4
79/79 [==============================] - 71s 895ms/step
79/79 [==============================] - 71s 895ms/step
468/468 [==============================] - 117s 250ms/step - loss: 0.0279 - accuracy: 0.9916 - val_loss: 0.0398 - val_accuracy: 0.9874
Epoch 6/15
466/468 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0225 - accuracy: 0.9930INFO:tensorflow:Running validation at fit epoch: 5
79/79 [==============================] - 79s 1s/step
79/79 [==============================] - 79s 1s/step
468/468 [==============================] - 129s 276ms/step - loss: 0.0224 - accuracy: 0.9930 - val_loss: 0.0390 - val_accuracy: 0.9877
Epoch 7/15
459/468 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0204 - accuracy: 0.9936INFO:tensorflow:Running validation at fit epoch: 6
79/79 [==============================] - 78s 984ms/step
79/79 [==============================] - 78s 984ms/step
468/468 [==============================] - 129s 277ms/step - loss: 0.0205 - accuracy: 0.9936 - val_loss: 0.0320 - val_accuracy: 0.9896
Epoch 8/15
465/468 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0165 - accuracy: 0.9945INFO:tensorflow:Running validation at fit epoch: 7
79/79 [==============================] - 81s 1s/step
79/79 [==============================] - 81s 1s/step
468/468 [==============================] - 135s 289ms/step - loss: 0.0164 - accuracy: 0.9945 - val_loss: 0.0403 - val_accuracy: 0.9889
Epoch 9/15
466/468 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0156 - accuracy: 0.9947INFO:tensorflow:Running validation at fit epoch: 8
79/79 [==============================] - 82s 1s/step
79/79 [==============================] - 82s 1s/step
468/468 [==============================] - 138s 295ms/step - loss: 0.0156 - accuracy: 0.9947 - val_loss: 0.0464 - val_accuracy: 0.9875
Epoch 10/15
460/468 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0139 - accuracy: 0.9954INFO:tensorflow:Running validation at fit epoch: 9
79/79 [==============================] - 89s 1s/step
79/79 [==============================] - 89s 1s/step
468/468 [==============================] - 147s 315ms/step - loss: 0.0137 - accuracy: 0.9954 - val_loss: 0.0431 - val_accuracy: 0.9903
Epoch 11/15
467/468 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0116 - accuracy: 0.9963INFO:tensorflow:Running validation at fit epoch: 10
79/79 [==============================] - 84s 1s/step
79/79 [==============================] - 84s 1s/step
468/468 [==============================] - 140s 298ms/step - loss: 0.0116 - accuracy: 0.9963 - val_loss: 0.0409 - val_accuracy: 0.9876
Epoch 12/15
459/468 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0116 - accuracy: 0.9963INFO:tensorflow:Running validation at fit epoch: 11
79/79 [==============================] - 85s 1s/step
79/79 [==============================] - 85s 1s/step
468/468 [==============================] - 148s 316ms/step - loss: 0.0117 - accuracy: 0.9963 - val_loss: 0.0466 - val_accuracy: 0.9870
Epoch 13/15
460/468 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0104 - accuracy: 0.9965INFO:tensorflow:Running validation at fit epoch: 12
79/79 [==============================] - 98s 1s/step
79/79 [==============================] - 98s 1s/step
468/468 [==============================] - 162s 347ms/step - loss: 0.0103 - accuracy: 0.9965 - val_loss: 0.0473 - val_accuracy: 0.9890
Epoch 14/15
461/468 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0095 - accuracy: 0.9966INFO:tensorflow:Running validation at fit epoch: 13
79/79 [==============================] - 101s 1s/step
79/79 [==============================] - 101s 1s/step
468/468 [==============================] - 168s 360ms/step - loss: 0.0094 - accuracy: 0.9967 - val_loss: 0.0421 - val_accuracy: 0.9905
Epoch 15/15
460/468 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0094 - accuracy: 0.9969INFO:tensorflow:Running validation at fit epoch: 14
79/79 [==============================] - 107s 1s/step
79/79 [==============================] - 107s 1s/step
468/468 [==============================] - 177s 379ms/step - loss: 0.0093 - accuracy: 0.9970 - val_loss: 0.0445 - val_accuracy: 0.9893
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f17b43c5f98>
```

Thanks

Comment: Run it a couple more times -- probably it's the random initialization difference

Comment: Thanks, this may be a possibility. I will ensure proper inits and then will check this again.

Comment: Try and use random.seed so that the random initialisation does not lead to different results.

Comment: @user3586512, Can you please confirm if the error is resolved with the comment mentioned above so that we can mention it as an Answer for the benefit of the Community. Else, please let us know so that we will try to help you ? Thanks !